Use captionsetup to change font colour but keep other font properties
I have my own environment that changes the colour of all text (along with some other stuff):
\newenvironment{revision}[1][1]{%
    \color{\revcolour}%
    \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour,linkcolor=\revcolour}%
    \captionsetup*{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \captionsetup*[sub]{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \makeatletter%
    \let\oldtable\table%
    \def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}%
    \def\table@i[#1]{\oldtable[#1]\color{\revcolour}}%
    \def\table@ii{\oldtable\color{\revcolour}}%
    \makeatother%
}{}

This has worked fine with everything I've encountered so far, except for figure captions. The issue is that the two \captionsetup lines change not only the font colour to blue but also all other font properties back to their defaults. Is there a way to change only the font colour, while leaving all other properties alone? Or at least a way of accessing the old font's properties (in a robust way, since I use this environment in most of my projects with different style files) so I can set them explicitly in the \captionsetup?
For example, I'd like the Figure 2 caption below to have the same size and font family as Figure 1 (but keep the blue colour it currently has):
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\revcolour}{blue}  % colour of revised text

\newenvironment{revision}[1][1]{%
    \color{\revcolour}%
    \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour,linkcolor=\revcolour}%
    \captionsetup*{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \captionsetup*[sub]{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \makeatletter%
    \let\oldtable\table%
    \def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}%
    \def\table@i[#1]{\oldtable[#1]\color{\revcolour}}%
    \def\table@ii{\oldtable\color{\revcolour}}%
    \makeatother%
}{}

\captionsetup{font={scriptsize,sf}}

\begin{document}

A towel, it says, is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitchhiker can have (see Fig.~\ref{fig:a}).

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon; use it to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you -- daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough.}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\begin{revision}

More importantly, a towel has immense psychological value. For some reason, if a strag (strag: non-hitch hiker) discovers that a hitch hiker has his towel with him, he will automatically assume that he is also in possession of a toothbrush, face flannel, soap, tin of biscuits, flask, compass, map, ball of string, gnat spray, wet weather gear, space suit etc., etc. More in Fig.~\ref{fig:b}.

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Furthermore, the strag will then happily lend the hitch hiker any of these or a dozen other items that the hitch hiker might accidentally have "lost". What the strag will think is that any man who can hitch the length and breadth of the galaxy, rough it, slum it, struggle against terrible odds, win through, and still knows where his towel is is clearly a man to be reckoned with.}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}

\end{revision}

\end{document}



Use font+ to append format to your captions (also labelfont+ and textfont+ are available for label and caption text, respectively)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\revcolour}{blue}  % colour of revised text

\newenvironment{revision}[1][1]{%
    \color{\revcolour}%
    \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour,linkcolor=\revcolour}%
    \captionsetup*{font+={color=\revcolour}}%
    \captionsetup*[sub]{font+={color=\revcolour}}%
    \makeatletter%
    \let\oldtable\table%
    \def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}%
    \def\table@i[#1]{\oldtable[#1]\color{\revcolour}}%
    \def\table@ii{\oldtable\color{\revcolour}}%
    \makeatother%
}{}

\captionsetup{font={scriptsize,sf}}

\begin{document}
    
    A towel, it says, is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitchhiker can have (see Fig.~\ref{fig:a}).
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon; use it to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you -- daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough.}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{revision}
        
        More importantly, a towel has immense psychological value. For some reason, if a strag (strag: non-hitch hiker) discovers that a hitch hiker has his towel with him, he will automatically assume that he is also in possession of a toothbrush, face flannel, soap, tin of biscuits, flask, compass, map, ball of string, gnat spray, wet weather gear, space suit etc., etc. More in Fig.~\ref{fig:b}.
        
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Furthermore, the strag will then happily lend the hitch hiker any of these or a dozen other items that the hitch hiker might accidentally have "lost". What the strag will think is that any man who can hitch the length and breadth of the galaxy, rough it, slum it, struggle against terrible odds, win through, and still knows where his towel is is clearly a man to be reckoned with.}
            \label{fig:b}
        \end{figure}
        
    \end{revision}
    
\end{document}



Excellent, precisely what I was looking for.
